# CUDA for Anaconda requires conflicting versions

Tags: python, nvidia-graphics-card, cuda, anaconda

I'm trying to install CUDA toolkit so that I can run Python code in parallel, but I'm having major problems. When I install CUDA, I get the error

**"Unsupported .version 6.3; current version is '6.2'."**

According to forums this means I need to roll back to CUDA 6.2 because that's what my hardware supports. But when I install an earlier version of CUDA I get the error that I have to use CUDA 7.5:

**RuntimeError: Missing libdevice file for compute_50. Please ensure you have package cudatoolkit 7.5.**

Obviously I can't both use CUDA 6.2 or below and CUDA 7.5 or above. My graphics card (GEForce 1060 Max Q) drivers are up to date and the computer is a brand new Razer Blade running Win10. What can I do to resolve this?